# Should I be using the Android Menu?

Tags: android, android-layout

I started learning Android just recently. I'm making a project app for myself, to keep track of the freelance projects I work on, and it's going quite okay. Although now I'm a bit stuck wondering if I should use the Android Menu tag for my navigation or not.

This is a quick mockup of the app:
[image]

As you can see I'm using a navigation bar at the left side of the app. I have no navigationbar at the top.
By choosing one of the items left, the content right should change the fragment that is used in the framelayout. I have the fragment and framelayout with the fragment in it atm, but now I'm stuck wondering what I should do with the navigation (in order to put the navigation items in that fragment).
Should I do this with a list view (and use the ListFragment), with just buttons or should I do this with the menu that comes with the Android SDK? And if its with the Menu layout, can I style this enough to have the design that I want?

Hope someone can help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tablet and phone layout you want different layouts with different navigation.

For the tablet version, I would recommend you to use custom buttons (e.g. `ImageButton`), with OnClickListeners that change your Fragment content.

For the phone version, you can utilize Android's Action Bar. You can do a drop-down navigation with it like you want in your sketch.
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

I think you do not want to implement the Menu for the navigation. It is usually used for settings or some more hidden actions. Your navigation should be obvious to the user and self-explanatory.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll use regular buttons with android:drawableTop for tablet (in case I ever wanted to have multiple languages in app) :-)